# Identifying this IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

[image: IC]

This is a kind of triple half bridge driver I guess (I may be wrong).

It resides right in front of three half bridges, or dual N-MOSFETs (FDMC8030).

Pin 9 and 15 are GND.
Pin 10 is 3V3.

Can you help me identify it?

---

I guess it is something similar to this:

[image: this]

Comment: Fwiw, the logo in the upper left corner is Infineon Technologies' old logo.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright it is a: XMC1302-Q024F0016 AB.

Infineon helped to identify it.

Answer (score 0):

The package seems to be a QFN-24. I found a few triple half bridges online that use this package, but none seem to match the pinout (There a two or more pins per side that have no traces leading away, I assume those are connected to ground).
MPQ6523 would be my best guess, but it does not match the pinout.

Can you confirm they are ground pins and potentially identify the vcc pin? I think that would help comparing it to other ICs.

Comment: Pin 9 and 15 are GND. Pin 10 is 3V3.

Comment: I might have mislead you. The half bridges are not inside the pictured IC. They are separate ICs. In fact they are Dual N-MOSFETs FDMC8030.